# Reflection - use apply with String param

Tags: scala, reflection

How I can find apply method for single String parameter for given `Type` ?

I have:

```
val param: String = ctx.request.uri.query.get(fName) //string param
val fType: scala.reflect.api.Type = field.typeSignature.resultType //desirable type
```

EDIT:

As a matter of fact I want to make Spray.io directive that extract many parameters from request to case class. Here you have an example:

https://gist.github.com/mgosk/25b9f01abf98eae159d1

- In first step I create instance of case class based on default parameters (`default` function)
- In second step I want to imbue this case class with parameters extracted from HTTP request (`imbue` function)

I want to improve this big match (`line 109`) from gist. In this moment I serve basic scala types, but I want to add handling for user defined types that have `apply(foo:String)` function .

Comment: try to elaborate your question a little bit more, ideally, provide a compilable code

Comment: You don't need reflection for this - the whole point of spray is that everything's typesafe and built on shapeless. So you can `hmap` a directive and use [shapeless Generic](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes) (that's the shapeless 2 documentation, if you're using spray-routing-shapeless2; if you're using the shapeless 1.x build then use `Iso`) to map between `HList`s and your case classes, no reflection necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

```
val param: String = ctx.request.uri.query.get(fName) //string param
val fType: scala.reflect.api.Type = field.typeSignature.resultType //desirable type 

val classMirror = currentMirror.reflectClass(fType.typeSymbol.asClass)
val ctor = fType.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
val value = classMirror.reflectConstructor(ctor).apply(param)
```

---

PS. It works only with classes that have corresponding constructor